# Consulta SQL, LINQ

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT tp.Nombre, 
       tp.IdTipoContacto
FROM TipoContacto tp 
LEFT JOIN Contacto c 
     on tp.IdTipoContacto = c.IdTipoContacto
WHERE NOT tp.Nombre = 'Compañia'
```

Esto me retorna

```
Facturacion 2
Facturacion 2
```

En mi tabla `TipoContacto` solo tengo dos registros que son **Facturacion** y **Compañia** en mi tabla `Contacto` tengo registros, varios son de `Facturacion`, y solo uno de `compañia`.

Quiero lograr que mi consulta solo retorne los registros que quedan de la tabla **TipoContacto** cuando el id de `compañia` ya exista en la otra tabla, en caso contrario listarme los dos `Facturacion` y `Compañia`, 
**adicionalmente que sea en Linq**

Como ven la consulta me trae dos iguales solo necesitaría uno en este caso Gracias

Algo Adicional Para Hacerme entender mejor:

**seleccionar registros, que cumplan con las siguientes condiciones
Tablas: Contacto, TipoContacto, Cliente**

**1. si ya heciste un contacto con tipoContacto Compañia, de un cliente especificado Solo listar Los demas.**

**2. si no hay ningun contacto con tipoContacto Compañia, de un cliente espefidicado listar todos incluyendo compañia.**

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haria en dos consultas distintas comprobando primero si existe ya compañia.

```
var query;

If (Contacto.Exists( c => c.TipoContacto.Name == "Compañia")
{
 query = Contacto.Where( c => c.TipoContacto.Name == "Compañia");

}else
{
query = Contacto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes utilizar Distinct.

```
var query = TipoContacto.Join(Contacto,
    c => c.IdTipoContacto,
    o => o.IdTipoContacto,
    (c, o) => new 
    {Nombre = c.Nombre, IdTipoContacto = o.IdTipoContacto})
        .Where(p=>p.Nombre != "Compañia").Distinct();
```

Supongo que la estructura de Cliente incluye ya sea Nombre o TipoContacto. 
si es así solo tendrías que hacer un query como este:

```
var isUsuario =UsuarioL.Where(p => p.Nombre == "Compañia").Select(p => p.Nombre);
```

Usa su resultado para decidir si tienes que usar el where o no. o el distict si también asi lo requieres.

```
var isUsuario =UsuarioL.Where(p => p.Nombre == "Compañia").Select(p => p.Nombre);
    if(isUsuario.FirstOrDefault() == "Compañia"){   
        var query = LTipoContacto.Join(LContacto,
        c => c.IdTipoContacto,
        o => o.IdTipoContacto,
        (c, o) => new 
        {Nombre = c.Nombre, IdTipoContacto = o.IdTipoContacto})
        .Where(p=>p.Nombre != "Compañia").Distinct();
    }
    else{
        var query = LTipoContacto.Join(LContacto,
        c => c.IdTipoContacto,
        o => o.IdTipoContacto,
        (c, o) => new 
        {Nombre = c.Nombre, IdTipoContacto = o.IdTipoContacto})
        .Distinct();
    }
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/hocPvh

Comment: No Funciona, no tiene sintaxis correcta

Comment: no Found, es decir si le decimos que sea diferente de Compañía, va a traer solo los de Facturación, pero si no tenemos un contacto de compañía relacionado a un cliente, entonces seguiria trayendo solo Facturación, y debería de traer los dos

Comment: @KmiiloBerrioMontoya modifique la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Encierra tu consulta LINQ de esta manera:

```
var result = (from tp in TipoContacto
    from c in Contacto
            .Where(c => c.IdTipoContacto == tp.IdTipoContacto)
            .DefaultIfEmpty()
    where tp.Nombre != "Compañia"
    select new 
    {
        Nombre = tp.Nombre,
        IdTipoContacto = tp.IdTipoContacto
    }).Distinct();
```

*Respuesta adaptada de estas [respuestas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4319029/4092887) en [inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4739738/4092887).*

Comment: no Found, es decir si le decimos que sea diferente de Compañía, va a traer solo los de Facturación, pero si no tenemos un contacto de compañía relacionado a  un cliente, entonces seguiria trayendo solo Facturación, y debería de traer los dos